# Case When Sequential Character Values and Time Greater Than Specified Interval

Tags: r

**Reprex**:

```
data
# A tibble: 82 x 12
# Groups:   SUBJ_ID, READER [2]
   SUBJ_ID VISIT DOS        MOS_DUR READER   SPD SPD_NADIR PCT_DIFF_NADIR SPD_BL PCT_DIFF_BL
   <chr>   <chr> <date>       <dbl> <fct>  <dbl>     <dbl>          <dbl>  <dbl>       <dbl>
 1 1002-3~ 1 Sc~ 2012-06-13   0     2       275.      275.         NA       275.      NA    
 2 1002-3~ 1 We~ 2012-07-12   0.967 2       358.      275.          0.302   275.       0.302
 3 1002-3~ 1 We~ 2012-08-09   1.87  2       439.      275.          0.594   275.       0.594
 4 1002-3~ 1 We~ 2012-09-18   3.17  2       528.      275.          0.919   275.       0.919
 5 1002-3~ Unsc~ 2012-10-25   4.39  2       584.      275.          1.12    275.       1.12 
 6 1002-3~ Unsc~ 2012-12-20   6.23  2       573.      275.          1.08    275.       1.08 
 7 1002-3~ Unsc~ 2013-02-13   8     2       516.      275.          0.872   275.       0.872
 8 1002-3~ Unsc~ 2013-03-29   9.52  2       532.      275.          0.930   275.       0.930
 9 1002-3~ Unsc~ 2013-05-14  11.0   2       534.      275.          0.941   275.       0.941
10 1002-3~ Unsc~ 2013-08-20  14.2   2       419.      275.          0.522   275.       0.522
# ... with 72 more rows, and 2 more variables: PROG <chr>, PRGMOS <dbl>
```

```
dput(data)
structure(list(SUBJ_ID = c("1002-31169", "1002-31169", "1002-31169", 
"1002-31169", "1002-31169", "1002-31169", "1002-31169", "1002-31169", 
"1002-31169", "1002-31169", "1002-31169", "1002-31169", "1002-31169", 
"1002-31169", "1002-31169", "1002-31169", "1002-31169", "1002-31169", 
"1002-31169", "1002-31169", "1002-31169", "1002-31169", "1002-31169", 
"1002-31169", "1002-31169", "1002-31169", "1002-31169", "1002-31169", 
"1002-31169", "1002-31169", "1002-31169", "1002-31169", "1002-31169", 
"1002-31169", "1002-31169", "1002-31169", "1002-31169", "1002-31169", 
"1002-31169", "1002-31169", "1002-31169", "1002-31169", "1002-31169", 
"1002-31169", "1002-31169", "1002-31169", "1002-31169", "1002-31169", 
"1002-31169", "1002-31169", "1002-31169", "1002-31169", "1002-31169", 
"1002-31169", "1002-31169", "1002-31169", "1002-31169", "1002-31169", 
"1002-31169", "1002-31169", "1002-31169", "1002-31169", "1002-31169", 
"1002-31169", "1002-31169", "1002-31169", "1002-31169", "1002-31169", 
"1002-31169", "1002-31169", "1002-31169", "1002-31169", "1002-31169", 
"1002-31169", "1002-31169", "1002-31169", "1002-31169", "1002-31169", 
"1002-31169", "1002-31169", "1002-31169", "1002-31169"), VISIT = c("1 Screening", 
"1 Week 04", "1 Week 08", "1 Week 16", "Unscheduled 01", "Unscheduled 02", 
"Unscheduled 03", "Unscheduled 04", "Unscheduled 05", "Unscheduled 06", 
"Unscheduled 07", "Unscheduled 08", "Unscheduled 09", "Unscheduled 10", 
"Unscheduled 11", "Unscheduled 12", "Unscheduled 13", "Unscheduled 14", 
"Unscheduled 15", "Unscheduled 16", "Unscheduled 17", "2 Screening", 
"2 Week 04", "2 Week 08", "2 Week 16", "Unscheduled 18", "Unscheduled 19", 
"Unscheduled 20", "Unscheduled 21", "Unscheduled 22", "Unscheduled 23", 
"3 Screening", "3 Week 04", "3 Week 08", "3 Week 16", "Unscheduled 24", 
"Unscheduled 25", "Unscheduled 26", "Unscheduled 27", "Unscheduled 28", 
"Unscheduled 29", "1 Screening", "1 Week 04", "1 Week 08", "1 Week 16", 
"Unscheduled 01", "Unscheduled 02", "Unscheduled 03", "Unscheduled 04", 
"Unscheduled 05", "Unscheduled 06", "Unscheduled 07", "Unscheduled 08", 
"Unscheduled 09", "Unscheduled 10", "Unscheduled 11", "Unscheduled 12", 
"Unscheduled 13", "Unscheduled 14", "Unscheduled 15", "Unscheduled 16", 
"Unscheduled 17", "2 Screening", "2 Week 04", "2 Week 08", "2 Week 16", 
"Unscheduled 18", "Unscheduled 19", "Unscheduled 20", "Unscheduled 21", 
"Unscheduled 22", "Unscheduled 23", "3 Screening", "3 Week 04", 
"3 Week 08", "3 Week 16", "Unscheduled 24", "Unscheduled 25", 
"Unscheduled 26", "Unscheduled 27", "Unscheduled 28", "Unscheduled 29"
), DOS = structure(c(15504, 15533, 15561, 15601, 15638, 15694, 
15749, 15793, 15839, 15937, 16027, 16153, 16272, 16398, 16552, 
16680, 16909, 16972, 17028, 17119, 17252, 17316, 17343, 17371, 
17427, 17490, 17553, 17609, 17665, 17756, 17840, 17862, 17896, 
17924, 17980, 17988, 18036, 18092, 18148, 18231, 18326, 15504, 
15533, 15561, 15601, 15638, 15694, 15749, 15793, 15839, 15937, 
16027, 16153, 16272, 16398, 16552, 16680, 16909, 16972, 17028, 
17119, 17252, 17316, 17343, 17371, 17427, 17490, 17553, 17609, 
17665, 17756, 17840, 17862, 17896, 17924, 17980, 17988, 18036, 
18092, 18148, 18231, 18326), class = "Date"), MOS_DUR = c(0, 
0.966666666666667, 1.87096774193548, 3.16666666666667, 4.38709677419355, 
6.2258064516129, 8, 9.51612903225806, 11.0322580645161, 14.2258064516129, 
17.1666666666667, 21.3548387096774, 25.258064516129, 29.3666666666667, 
34.4666666666667, 38.6451612903226, 46.1666666666667, 48.2333333333333, 
50.0645161290323, 53.0333333333333, 57.4516129032258, 59.5483870967742, 
60.4333333333333, 61.3548387096774, 63.1666666666667, 65.2333333333333, 
67.2903225806452, 69.1935483870968, 71.0322580645161, 74, 76.741935483871, 
77.4666666666667, 78.5806451612903, 79.4838709677419, 81.3870967741936, 
81.6451612903226, 83.2258064516129, 85.0645161290323, 86.8709677419355, 
89.6, 92.7241379310345, 0, 0.966666666666667, 1.87096774193548, 
3.16666666666667, 4.38709677419355, 6.2258064516129, 8, 9.51612903225806, 
11.0322580645161, 14.2258064516129, 17.1666666666667, 21.3548387096774, 
25.258064516129, 29.3666666666667, 34.4666666666667, 38.6451612903226, 
46.1666666666667, 48.2333333333333, 50.0645161290323, 53.0333333333333, 
57.4516129032258, 59.5483870967742, 60.4333333333333, 61.3548387096774, 
63.1666666666667, 65.2333333333333, 67.2903225806452, 69.1935483870968, 
71.0322580645161, 74, 76.741935483871, 77.4666666666667, 78.5806451612903, 
79.4838709677419, 81.3870967741936, 81.6451612903226, 83.2258064516129, 
85.0645161290323, 86.8709677419355, 89.6, 92.7241379310345), 
    READER = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("1", 
    "2", "3", "4", "5"), class = "factor"), SPD = c(275.32, 358.49, 
    438.99, 528.38, 583.55, 572.93, 515.5, 531.5, 534.4, 419.07, 
    328.02, 145.58, 146.78, 165.25, 136.49, 200.55, 170.55, 271.51, 
    243.32, 356.41, 447.68, 526.89, 586.47, 619.36, 666.5, 625.72, 
    679.19, 639.81, 638.95, 686.85, 920.76, 992.07, 1131.35, 
    1092.71, 1405.81, 1692.02, 1553.67, 2074.41, 2056.49, 1281.96, 
    1944.41, 361.13, 488.18, 581.76, 623.45, 730.45, 639.17, 
    545.33, 564.94, 633.28, 491.78, 434.64, 203.66, 154.57, 229.18, 
    148.35, 132.52, 152.16, 288.91, 334.22, 420.01, 688.19, 645.57, 
    630.8, 683.63, 758.01, 642.23, 636.91, 691.11, 708.32, 579.91, 
    884.35, 1193.26, 1377.71, 1208.79, 1555.86, 1737.75, 1616, 
    2003.85, 2190.7, 1353.92, 2239.47), SPD_NADIR = c(275.32, 
    275.32, 275.32, 275.32, 275.32, 275.32, 275.32, 275.32, 275.32, 
    275.32, 275.32, 145.58, 145.58, 145.58, 136.49, 136.49, 136.49, 
    136.49, 136.49, 136.49, 136.49, 136.49, 136.49, 136.49, 136.49, 
    136.49, 136.49, 136.49, 136.49, 136.49, 136.49, 136.49, 136.49, 
    136.49, 136.49, 136.49, 136.49, 136.49, 136.49, 136.49, 136.49, 
    361.13, 361.13, 361.13, 361.13, 361.13, 361.13, 361.13, 361.13, 
    361.13, 361.13, 361.13, 203.66, 154.57, 154.57, 148.35, 132.52, 
    132.52, 132.52, 132.52, 132.52, 132.52, 132.52, 132.52, 132.52, 
    132.52, 132.52, 132.52, 132.52, 132.52, 132.52, 132.52, 132.52, 
    132.52, 132.52, 132.52, 132.52, 132.52, 132.52, 132.52, 132.52, 
    132.52), PCT_DIFF_NADIR = c(NA, 0.302084846723812, 0.594471887258463, 
    0.919148627052157, 1.11953363359, 1.08096033706233, 0.872366700566613, 
    0.930480894958594, 0.94101409269214, 0.522119715240448, 0.191413627778585, 
    -0.47123347377597, 0.00824289050693769, 0.135114713559555, 
    -0.0624398955900536, 0.469338413070555, 0.249542090995677, 
    0.989229980218331, 0.782694702908638, 1.61125357169023, 2.2799472488827, 
    2.86028280460107, 3.29679830024178, 3.53776833467653, 3.88314162209686, 
    3.58436515495641, 3.97611546633453, 3.68759616089091, 3.68129533299143, 
    4.03223679390431, 5.74598871712213, 6.26844457469412, 7.28888563264708, 
    7.00578796981464, 9.29972891786944, 11.3966590959045, 10.3830317239358, 
    14.1982562825115, 14.0669646127921, 8.39233643490366, 13.2458055535204, 
    NA, 0.35181236673774, 0.610943427574558, 0.726386619776812, 
    1.02267881372359, 0.769916650513665, 0.510065627336416, 0.564367402320494, 
    0.753606734416969, 0.36178107606679, 0.203555506327361, -0.436047960568216, 
    -0.241038986546204, 0.482693925082487, -0.040240667658666, 
    -0.106707111560499, 0.148204044672502, 1.18012375490492, 
    1.52203440990039, 2.16940839118624, 4.19310292785995, 3.87149109568367, 
    3.76003622094778, 4.15869302746755, 4.71996679746453, 3.8462873528524, 
    3.80614246906127, 4.21513733776034, 4.34500452761847, 3.37601871415635, 
    5.67333232719589, 8.00437669785693, 9.39624207666767, 8.12156655599155, 
    10.7405674615152, 12.1131150015092, 11.1943857530939, 14.1211137941443, 
    15.5310896468458, 9.21672200422578, 15.899109568367), SPD_BL = c(275.32, 
    275.32, 275.32, 275.32, 275.32, 275.32, 275.32, 275.32, 275.32, 
    275.32, 275.32, 275.32, 275.32, 275.32, 275.32, 275.32, 275.32, 
    275.32, 275.32, 275.32, 275.32, 275.32, 275.32, 275.32, 275.32, 
    275.32, 275.32, 275.32, 275.32, 275.32, 275.32, 275.32, 275.32, 
    275.32, 275.32, 275.32, 275.32, 275.32, 275.32, 275.32, 275.32, 
    361.13, 361.13, 361.13, 361.13, 361.13, 361.13, 361.13, 361.13, 
    361.13, 361.13, 361.13, 361.13, 361.13, 361.13, 361.13, 361.13, 
    361.13, 361.13, 361.13, 361.13, 361.13, 361.13, 361.13, 361.13, 
    361.13, 361.13, 361.13, 361.13, 361.13, 361.13, 361.13, 361.13, 
    361.13, 361.13, 361.13, 361.13, 361.13, 361.13, 361.13, 361.13, 
    361.13), PCT_DIFF_BL = c(NA, 0.302084846723812, 0.594471887258463, 
    0.919148627052157, 1.11953363359, 1.08096033706233, 0.872366700566613, 
    0.930480894958594, 0.94101409269214, 0.522119715240448, 0.191413627778585, 
    -0.47123347377597, -0.466874909196571, -0.399789336045329, 
    -0.504249600464914, -0.271574894668023, -0.380539009152986, 
    -0.0138384425395903, -0.11622838878396, 0.294530001452855, 
    0.626035159087607, 0.913736742699404, 1.13013947406654, 1.24960046491356, 
    1.42081941014093, 1.27270085718437, 1.46691123056807, 1.3238776696208, 
    1.32075403167224, 1.49473340113323, 2.34432660177248, 2.60333430190324, 
    3.10921836408543, 2.9688725846288, 4.10609472613686, 5.1456486996949, 
    4.64314252506175, 6.53454162429173, 6.46945372657271, 3.65625454017144, 
    6.06236379485689, NA, 0.35181236673774, 0.610943427574558, 
    0.726386619776812, 1.02267881372359, 0.769916650513665, 0.510065627336416, 
    0.564367402320494, 0.753606734416969, 0.36178107606679, 0.203555506327361, 
    -0.436047960568216, -0.571982388613519, -0.365380887768947, 
    -0.589206103065378, -0.633040733253953, -0.578655885692133, 
    -0.199983385484451, -0.0745161022346523, 0.16304377924847, 
    0.905657242544236, 0.787638800431978, 0.746739401323623, 
    0.893030210727439, 1.09899482180932, 0.778390053443358, 0.763658516323761, 
    0.913742973444466, 0.961398942209177, 0.605820618613796, 
    1.4488411375405, 2.30423947055077, 2.81499736936837, 2.34724337496192, 
    3.30831002686013, 3.81197906571041, 3.47484285437377, 4.54883283028272, 
    5.06623653531969, 2.7491208152189, 5.20128485586908), PROG = c(NA, 
    "PDu", "PDu", "PDu", "PDu", "PDc", "PDc", "PDc", "PDc", "PDc", 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "PDc", NA, "PDc", "PDc", "PDc", "PDc", 
    "PDc", "PDc", "PDc", "PDc", "PDc", "PDc", "PDc", "PDc", "PDc", 
    "PDc", "PDc", "PDc", "PDc", "PDc", "PDc", "PDc", "PDc", "PDc", 
    "PDc", "PDc", NA, "PDu", "PDu", "PDu", "PDu", "PDc", "PDc", 
    "PDc", "PDc", "PDc", NA, NA, NA, "PDc", NA, NA, NA, "PDc", 
    "PDc", "PDc", "PDc", "PDc", "PDc", "PDc", "PDc", "PDc", "PDc", 
    "PDc", "PDc", "PDc", "PDc", "PDc", "PDc", "PDc", "PDc", "PDc", 
    "PDc", "PDc", "PDc", "PDc", "PDc"), PRGMOS = c(NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, 4.38709677419355, 6.2258064516129, 8, 9.51612903225806, 
    11.0322580645161, 14.2258064516129, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 38.6451612903226, 
    NA, 48.2333333333333, 50.0645161290323, 53.0333333333333, 
    57.4516129032258, 59.5483870967742, 60.4333333333333, 61.3548387096774, 
    63.1666666666667, 65.2333333333333, 67.2903225806452, 69.1935483870968, 
    71.0322580645161, 74, 76.741935483871, 77.4666666666667, 
    78.5806451612903, 79.4838709677419, 81.3870967741936, 81.6451612903226, 
    83.2258064516129, 85.0645161290323, 86.8709677419355, 89.6, 
    92.7241379310345, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4.38709677419355, 6.2258064516129, 
    8, 9.51612903225806, 11.0322580645161, 14.2258064516129, 
    NA, NA, NA, 29.3666666666667, NA, NA, NA, 48.2333333333333, 
    50.0645161290323, 53.0333333333333, 57.4516129032258, 59.5483870967742, 
    60.4333333333333, 61.3548387096774, 63.1666666666667, 65.2333333333333, 
    67.2903225806452, 69.1935483870968, 71.0322580645161, 74, 
    76.741935483871, 77.4666666666667, 78.5806451612903, 79.4838709677419, 
    81.3870967741936, 81.6451612903226, 83.2258064516129, 85.0645161290323, 
    86.8709677419355, 89.6, 92.7241379310345)), row.names = c(NA, 
-82L), groups = structure(list(SUBJ_ID = c("1002-31169", "1002-31169"
), READER = structure(c(2L, 4L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4", 
"5"), class = "factor"), .rows = structure(list(1:41, 42:82), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
"vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

**Problem**: I need to set `PDu` values to `PDc` when there are sequential `PDu` values and the time duration (difference in `MOS_DUR`) between the first occurrence and last occurrence is `>=3`. `PDu` can only occur when `MOS_DUR <= 6`. In the example given, the `PROG` value for the second scan (row 2) would be reset to `PDc` from `PDu`.

**Edit 1**: Added a `PROGMOS` variable to the reprex in an attempt to provide more clarity. Essentially, if there is a sequence where `last(PRGMOS) - first(PRGMOS) > 3 & PROG == "PDu"` `PDu` will then become a `PDc`.

This is my current code, but it is not doing what I want.

```
data <- data %>%
  group_by(SUBJ_ID, READER) %>%
  mutate(PROG = case_when(
           PCT_DIFF_NADIR >= 0.25 & MOS_DUR <= 6 ~ "PDu", 
           PCT_DIFF_NADIR >= 0.25 & MOS_DUR > 6 ~ "PDc"
          )) 

data <- data %>%
  group_by(SUBJ_ID, READER) %>%
  mutate(PRGMOS = case_when(
    PROG == "PDu" & lead(PROG) == "PDc" ~ MOS_DUR,
    PROG == "PDu" & lead(PROG) == "PDu" ~ MOS_DUR,
    PROG == "PDc"
  ))  %>%
  mutate(PRGFLG = case_when(
    max(PRGMOS) - min(PRGMOS) > 3 ~ 1,
  ))
```

*Edit 2**: Expected output example below:

```
> output
# A tibble: 33 x 5
   SUBJ_ID    READER MOS_DUR PROG  PROG2
   <chr>      <chr>    <dbl> <chr> <chr>
 1 1001-31169 4        0     NA    NA   
 2 1001-31169 4        0.903 PDu   PDc  
 3 1001-31169 4        2     PDu   PDc  
 4 1001-31169 4        3.58  PDu   PDc  
 5 1001-31169 4        5.42  PDu   PDc  
 6 1001-31169 4        7.26  NA    NA   
 7 1001-31169 4        9.07  NA    NA   
 8 1001-31169 4       11.0   NA    NA   
 9 1001-31169 4       14.2   NA    NA   
10 1001-31169 4       17.7   NA    NA   
# ... with 23 more rows
```

As you can see in the example above, the `PDu` was converted to `PDc` since `5.42-0.903 >3` and all `PDu`'s were in sequence.

Comment: Not clear abou tyour conditon.  May be `library(dplyr);library(data.table);df1 %>% group_by(SUBJ_ID, grp = rleid(PROG)) %>% mutate(PROG2 = case_when(all(PROG == 'PDu') & (last(MOS_DUR) - first(MOS_DUR)) >= 3 ~ 'PDc', TRUE ~ PROG) ) %>% ungroup`

Comment: I want to change the `PROG` value to `PDc` if time duration (`MOS_DUR`) between the first sequential `PDu` and last `PDu` in the sequence is >3.

Comment: @akrun added an example output. Hope that adds additional clarity.

Comment: In the initial 'data'. row6 onwards it is PDc,  are you converting to NA in expected ouptut

Comment: I want to leave them blank if the criteria is not met. I am going to use `coalesce` to fill in the missing with a different response variable.

Comment: IN that case, may be this works `data %>% group_by(SUBJ_ID, grp = rleid(PROG)) %>% mutate(PROG2 = case_when(all(PROG == 'PDu') & (last(MOS_DUR) - first(MOS_DUR)) >= 3 ~ 'PDc', TRUE ~ NA_character_) ) %>% ungroup`

Comment: So the problem with using `all()` is that you may have gaps between the `PDu`'s. I really need something like `while()`, but in a vectorized format. I can't use `lead()` or `lag()` either, since there may be sequential `PDu`s that are not >3 mos. apart. However, the first and last of the sequence may be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building off of @akrun code, here is the solution that I used:

```
data <- data %>%
  group_by(SUBJ_ID, READER) %>%
  mutate(PROG = case_when(
           PCT_DIFF_NADIR >= 0.25 & MOS_DUR <= 6 ~ "PDu", 
           PCT_DIFF_NADIR >= 0.25 & MOS_DUR > 6 ~ "PDc"
          )) 

data <- data %>% 
  group_by(SUBJ_ID, READER, grp = rleid(PROG)) %>% 
  mutate(PROG2 = case_when(
    all(PROG == 'PDu') & (last(MOS_DUR) - first(MOS_DUR)) >= 3 ~ 'PDc', 
    TRUE ~ PROG)) %>% 
    ungroup()
```

I needed to also `group_by(READER)` in addition to the other vars. Thanks again @akrun!